# What would be the best way to handle state in compose avoiding recomposition using a view model as a state handle?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building an android application to calculate the user's body mass index (BMI):

[image]

I'm not sure what would be the best way to handle the state using a view model as a state holder. For you to help me I will describe my problem as much as possible, starting with the files:

***HomeUiState.kt***

Responsible for storing the UI state.

```kotlin
data class HomeUiState(
    val weight: String,
    val height: String,
    val currentBmiCalculated: String,
)
```

***HomeViewModel.kt***

Responsible to control the UI state and handle actions to composable, like show a toast:

```kotlin
class HomeViewModel(
    private val firstState: HomeUiState,
    private val stringToFloatConvertor: StringToFloatConvertorUseCase,
    private val calculateBmi: CalculateBmiUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        private const val FIRST_VALUE = ""

        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                HomeViewModel(
                    stringToFloatConvertor = StringToFloatConvertorUseCaseImpl(),
                    calculateBmi = CalculateImcUseCaseImpl(),
                    firstState = HomeUiState(
                        weight = FIRST_VALUE,
                        height = FIRST_VALUE,
                        currentBmiCalculated = "Not calculated yet",
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<HomeUiState> = MutableStateFlow(firstState)
    private val _uiAction = MutableSharedFlow<HomeUiAction>()

    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    val uiAction = _uiAction.asSharedFlow()

    fun dispatchUiEvent(uiEvent: HomeUiEvent) {
        when (uiEvent) {
            is HomeUiEvent.OnEnterHeightValue -> _uiState.update { it.copy(height = uiEvent.value) }
            is HomeUiEvent.OnEnterWeightValue -> _uiState.update { it.copy(weight = uiEvent.value) }
            is HomeUiEvent.OnCalculateButtonClick -> onCalculateButtonClick()
            is HomeUiEvent.OnClearButtonClick -> {
                _uiState.update { firstState }
                emitAction(HomeUiAction.MoveCursorToHeight)
            }
            is HomeUiEvent.OnProfileIconClick -> emitAction(HomeUiAction.NavigateToProfileScreen)
        }
    }

    private fun onCalculateButtonClick() {
        stringToFloatConvertor(uiState.value.weight)?.let { weight ->
            stringToFloatConvertor(uiState.value.height)?.let { height ->
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(currentImcCalculated = "${calculateBmi(weight, height)}")
                }
            } ?: showErrorToast(R.string.invalid_height_value)
        } ?: showErrorToast(R.string.invalid_weight_value)
        emitAction(HomeUiAction.HideKeyboard)
    }

    private fun showErrorToast(@StringRes message: Int) =
        emitAction(HomeUiAction.ShowErrorToast(message))

    private fun emitAction(action: HomeUiAction) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiAction.emit(action)
        }
    }
}
```

### HomeScreen.kt

And so here I have my differences because I'm not sure if I should transmit my viewmodel entirely to the `HomeContent` or if I should do according to the recommendations of the [documentation itself of not transmitting the view model to the descendant functions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth:%7E:text=used%20for%20this.-,Warning%3A,-Don%27t%20pass%20ViewModel). But it seems to me that when breaking the ui state into several parameters for the `HomeContent`, when changing just 1 parameter would all `HomeContent` components be affected or not?
Just to clarify the options I'm considering:

#### Option 1 - Pass only the necessary to HomeContent:

That way, by breaking the UI state into multiple parameters, the entire function would be recomposed if 1 single parameter changes, right?

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester.Default }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        viewModel.uiAction.collectLatest { action ->
            when (action) {
                is HomeUiAction.ShowErrorToast -> Toast
                    .makeText(context, context.getText(action.messageId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                is HomeUiAction.MoveCursorToHeight -> focusRequester.requestFocus()
                is HomeUiAction.NavigateToProfileScreen -> navController.navigate("profile")
                is HomeUiAction.HideKeyboard -> keyboardController?.hide()
            }
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            HomeAppBar(
                onProfileClick = { viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnProfileIconClick) }
            )
        }
    ) {
        HomeContent(
            height = uiState.height,
            weight = uiState.weight,
            onHeightChange = {
                viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnEnterHeightValue(it))
            },
            onWeightChange = {
                viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnEnterWeightValue(it))
            },
            onClear = {
                viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnClearButtonClick)
            },
            onCalculate = {
                viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnCalculateButtonClick)
            },
            focusRequester = focusRequester,
            bmiResult = uiState.currentImcCalculated
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun HomeContent(
    height: String,
    weight: String,
    bmiResult: String,
    onHeightChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onWeightChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onClear: () -> Unit,
    onCalculate: () -> Unit,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "BMI Calculator",
            style = TextStyle(
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 24.sp
            )
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            BmiEditText(
                value = height,
                label = "Height (m)",
                onValueChange = onHeightChange,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(2 / 5f)
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1 / 3f))
            BmiEditText(
                value = weight,
                label = "Weight (kg)",
                onValueChange = onWeightChange,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = onCalculate) {
            Text(text = "Calculate")
        }
        Button(onClick = onClear) {
            Text(text = "Clear")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(text = "BMI result: $bmiResult")
    }
}
```

#### Option 2 - Pass the entire view model to HomeContent

That way, as the view model instance remains the same, the function would no longer be recomposed, right?

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester.Default }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        viewModel.uiAction.collectLatest { action ->
            when (action) {
                is HomeUiAction.ShowErrorToast -> Toast
                    .makeText(context, context.getText(action.messageId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                is HomeUiAction.MoveCursorToHeight -> focusRequester.requestFocus()
                is HomeUiAction.NavigateToProfileScreen -> navController.navigate("profile")
                is HomeUiAction.HideKeyboard -> keyboardController?.hide()
            }
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            HomeAppBar(
                onProfileClick = { viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnProfileIconClick) }
            )
        }
    ) {
        HomeContent(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            focusRequester = focusRequester,
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun HomeContent(
    viewModel: HomeViewModel,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "BMI Calculator",
            style = TextStyle(
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 24.sp
            )
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            BmiEditText(
                value = uiState.height,
                label = "Height (m)",
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnEnterHeightValue(it))
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(2 / 5f)
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1 / 3f))
            BmiEditText(
                value = uiState.weight,
                label = "Weight (kg)",
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnEnterWeightValue(it))
                },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(
            onClick = {
                viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnCalculateButtonClick)
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Calculate")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                viewModel.dispatchUiEvent(HomeUiEvent.OnClearButtonClick)
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Clear")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(text = "BMI result: ${uiState.currentBmiCalculated}")
    }
}
```

### Question

With these options in mind, **which of the two would be the best to avoid unnecessary recompositions following good community practices?**

Comment: I would recommend - "Pass only the necessary to HomeContent".

Comment: But in this case, wouldn't `HomeContent` completely unnecessarily recompose itself if 1 parameter changed? @Abhimanyu

Comment: If the screen is hosted inside an Activity/Fragment , you can pass the uiState only from the Activity/Fragment and listen to changes of the uistate (collectAsState) inside the Activity/Fragment, if you are using compose navigation just send the uiState to the screen and inside the composable { } block of your navigation NavHost pass the uiState only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 would be the one you should be using. Because you should never be passing the ViewModels down. The reason is that viewModels are marked as `unstable` by compose compiler and it causes the composable function `non-skippable`. The problem with this, recomposition will not be skipped and your UI elements will be redrawn even though the parameters you passed were not changed.

With Option 1, you are right that It will be recomposed if 1 parameters changed but since Compose can intelligently recompose only the components that changed, you would not have problem.

For detailed information you can check the following resources.

https://twitter.github.io/compose-rules/rules/

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8